# Python regular expression that will find words made out of specific letters. Letters must be used once only

Tags: python, regex

If I have a list of words in the variable words and a list of letters in the variable letters, how can I find all the words that can be made up out of the letters in letters. The letters in letters must only be used once each; but you can list the same letter more than once. All letters in letters must be used. I would like to do this in Python or Excel VBA.

For example:

```
letters = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'l', 'r', 's', 't', 'u']
words = ['dummy', 'australia']
```

Comment: I don't know if regex is the best approach or if it's even possible. It would be much easier and more maintainable to do it in pure Python.

Comment: Haven't tried anything. Not sure whether \1 to \9 with a ^\1 could be helpful. Although that would only work for 9 letter words

Comment: Doesn't have to be regex

Comment: @Cheezey It is possible using regex but this is probably not a good usage of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regex for this, especially in Python:

```
>>> [w for w in words if sorted(w) == letters]
['australia']
```

This assumes that `letters` is sorted, as in your example.

Comment: Shouldn't that be == instead of <=?

Comment: @Superdooperhero You're right, I missed the "All letters in letters must be used" part. Actually, in this case there's a simpler solution; edited.

Comment: Tested this and while it will probably be helpful, it's not entirely correct. Brings back ['altruist', 'latirus', 'ritualist', 'ruralist', 'trisula', 'ultraist']. The set converts the multiple a's to one a.

Comment: @Superdooperhero You probably should refresh the page :)

Comment: Sorted seems to have sorted it. :-)

Comment: @Superdooperhero I have to note that using `collections.Counter` may be slightly faster than sorting.